# Unity to Xcode Error: Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, linker, xcode8, google-cardboard

I'm trying to make a VR game using the Google Cardboard SDK and Unity. 
I'm using Xcode 8, and when I try to build to my iPhone I get an Apple Mach-O Linker Error

It says:

[image]

**Anyone know how to fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

If you built using Unity then one issue might be that you opened the .xcodeproj file. Instead look for and open the .xcworkspace in your build folder. This worked for me.

Comment: You've likely already solved this problem but for anyone else who may come across the same problem.

Comment: Hey I have built open Unity and I can't find .xcworkspace file. Can you help what else can I do?

Comment: @AyushMalviya Provide a screenshot of the projects folder directory. If you built using Unity with iOS selected as the platform it should be there

Comment: No, it isn't there but I have found what was causing the error I was trying to build for simulator and in unity, I have selected device sdk as target sdk so because of that the x86_64 libraries were missing that are needed to run the app on the simulator.

Comment: Great, glad you were able to find the problem. I suggest answering the initial question so it can be marked for other people who may come across the same issue.